# why i am unaware, not awake?

Tags: impermanence

I made you read the explaination and you are trying to get what is not available! What is that and why we do this? Why we want to be awake when we are totally unaware of being awake-state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are deep sleep (Bhavanga) you are unaware. When you are awake you do have some awareness ([Ekaggata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekaggata) - 1 of the 7 universal mental factors) but it not penetrating awareness as you do not have enough focus (Samadhi).

Answer (score 3):

> From an inconceivable beginning comes transmigration. A beginning point is not evident, though beings hindered by ignorance and fettered by craving are transmigrating & wandering on. [Assu Sutta: Tears](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn15/sn15.003.than_en.html)